# Flutter daily step count

Tags: flutter

I want to get daily step count in flutter. I use a pedometer but it shows me the total number of steps I have taken so far. How can I do the daily reset?
I am using Flutter version 1.22.6.
As soon as I entered the application, I wanted to keep the current step count with shared preferences and I aimed to find the daily number of steps by subtracting it from the current one. I could not do this because the stepcount event function was triggered. I am using the pedometer library from pub.dev. Any ideas?

Comment: Share your code: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Answer (score 0):

https://pub.dev/packages/pedometer

I know a solution only for iOS.

If you are using this package, you should modify native code.

https://github.com/cph-cachet/flutter-plugins/blob/master/packages/pedometer/ios/Classes/SwiftPedometerPlugin.swift

In above file, this blow code

```
else if (!running) {
    let systemUptime = ProcessInfo.processInfo.systemUptime;
    let timeNow = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
    let dateOfLastReboot = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: timeNow - systemUptime)
    running = true
    pedometer.startUpdates(from: dateOfLastReboot) {
```

could be changed like this.

```
else if (!running) {
    let dateOfTodayMidnight = Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: 0, minute: 0, second: 0, of: Date())!
    running = true
    pedometer.startUpdates(from: dateOfTodayMidnight) {
```

It works for iOS.

And... for Android it is far difficult. You should make more native code for that.